# Choose env from the Conda Prompt

Tags: python, conda

I made a script which uses nltk package, which I had installed into my base env. I want to make a few checks about dependencies.

I create a new env:

```
(base) C:\Users\Kosh>conda create --name newenv
```

then I activate it:

```
(base) C:\Users\Kosh>conda activate newenv
```

check if I am actually there:

```
(newenv) D:\Python\2gis>conda info

     active environment : newenv
```

and check if there are any packages there:

```
(newenv) D:\Python\2gis>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Anaconda3\envs\newenv:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
```

But when I run the script in my new env it runs, despite I had not installed nltk package there. In the same time when I run if from the Spyder(newenv) all is as expected:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk'
```

Any idea why it does use my base packages when executed from the Conda Prompt ?

Comment: From within your conda promt; try going into python shell and doing `import nltk` there. That will tell you confirm if the package is installed or not.

Comment: _I made a script which uses nltk package, which I had installed into my base env._ That's a bad idea, it's best not to fiddle with the base environment. _But when I run the script in my new env it runs, despite I had not installed nltk package there._ Are you entirely sure it was using the correct Python installation?